# Logging Options for the Intel's Multi-OS Engine

Tags: intel

In this [article](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/633268) from Intel documentation, they say that you can use Android Logging API for ios using Multi-OS Engine adding `migeran-android-lib.jar` file to the lib folder, but where is that file?

Answer (score 0):

Those guides are deprecated and mostly incorrect now. Android logging for MOE (multi-os-engine) projects is provided out of the box.

Just import `android.util.Log;`

And then use any of the logging options:

```
Log.i(TAG, "message");
Log.d(TAG, "message");
Log.e(TAG, "message");
```